# Using "stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring" for get the link in <a href='XXXX'> tag in objective C

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, stringbyevaluatingjavascr

I have html code like this

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href='001'><img src='chp1.png'/></a>
    <a href='002'><img src='chp2.png'/></a>
</body></html>
```

I want to get 001 or 002 in  by use stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring

like

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@""];
```

have anyone know how to get it

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` is a good choice here. Try using an `NSScanner`:

```
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:yourHTML];
while ([scanner scanUpToString:@"a href='" intoString:nil])
{
    [scanner scanString:@"a href='" intoString:nil];
    NSString* result = nil;
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"'" intoString:&result];
    //Do something with result, which will equal 001, then 002, etc.
}
```

Note that if you need to parse HTML you didn't write yourself, you'll need to add a lot more flexibility to this to account for possible stylistic differences (e.g. `'` vs `"`, `href` vs `HREF`).

Comment: If I print NSLog("%@",result);

the Result is

a href=
a href=
(NULL)

Comment: I just fixed a slight bug in it.